# Grab wordpress posts from a certain tag in JSON format

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress, api, plugins

Is there a way to grab the JSON feed of a series of wordpress posts *other* than using the JSON Rest API? 
http://wptavern.com/json-rest-api-slated-for-wordpress-4-1-release

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either within wordpress or outside of it to return this.

If you want to do this in wordpress you could a wordpress Ajax action then build the response in the custom function. Her is a simple example http://wptheming.com/2013/07/simple-ajax-example/

Otherwise outside of wordpress you would write a custom php page that connects to the wordpress database and queries the posts table for what you want. Then return the result as json. Here is an example tutorial, not Wordpress but it shows how it can be done https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/

Comment: The second tutorial you mentioned links to the plugin. Did you mean to put another link there? Thanks!

Comment: Oops yes you are right, that's what comes from working from an iPad. In fact there are quite a few tutorials on this. Here is another one with a simple example http://www.islandsmooth.com/2010/04/send-and-receive-json-data-using-ajax-jquery-and-php/